# Python String Spliting

Tags: python

`name = "Python"`

I want to split the variable name into 'Pyt' and 'hon' using the split method.

I have achieved this with `name[0:3]` and `name[3:]` and saving both of them in different variables but can it be done using a method ?

Comment: You mean split a string in half? Why not `name[:len(name)//2]` and `name[len(name)//2:]` (adjust parity to taste)? I don't think the dupe is related, BTW, but I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: Do you mean a method to split strings in half? The `split` method splits strings on a specific character, but its unclear how you wanted to split up your string in a generic way.

Comment: What do you mean with "using a method"? Can you give us an example of what you want to do?

Comment: If you want to use a method, `name.__getitem__(slice(3))`, `name.__getitem__(slice(3, None))`

Comment: If my string is Python I want to split the string into two but I get to choose what I want to split and it should retain the character on what I am splitting on